# Validator expression doesn't work for me in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I wanted to configure a validation expression type to verify that the sum of the four fields does not exceed 100

```xml
<validator type="expression" short-circuit="true">
    <param name="expression">
     (employee.analysis + employee.development + employee.test + employee.maintenance) gt 100
    </param>
    <message key="validations.error.total"/>
</validator>
```

but the above solution doesn't work

I have also tried this:

```xml
<validator type="expression" short-circuit="true">
    <param name="expression">
     <![CDATA[(employee.analysis + employee.development + employee.test + employee.maintenance) > 100 ]]>
    </param>
    <message key="validations.error.total"/>
</validator>
```

Comment: Yes , I have also tried

Comment: BTW the expression must be TRUE. So if you use `> 100`, the error will arise only if the value is LOWER than 100... try with `<= 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is this:

```
<validator type="expression" short-circuit="true">
    <param name="expression">
     <![CDATA[(employee.analysis + employee.development + employee.test + employee.maintenance) <= 100 ]]>
    </param>
    <message key="validations.error.total"/>
</validator>
```